# Python LinkExtractor to go to next pages doesn't work

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Next is a piece of code i have to try crawling a site with more then 1 page... i'm having troubles getting the rule class working. What am i doing wrong?

```
#import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from tutorial.items import SkodaItem

class SkodaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "skodas"
    allowed_domains = ["marktplaats.nl"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.marktplaats.nl/z/auto-s/skoda/octavia-trekhaak-stationwagon.html?categoryId=151&priceFrom=1.000%2C00&priceTo=15.000%2C00&yearFrom=2010&mileageTo=150.000&attributes=S%2C1185&attributes=S%2C484&attributes=M%2C11564&startDateFrom=always"
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button secondary medium pagination-next"]/a',)), follow=True),
    ]

#    def parse_item(self, response):
    def parse(self, response):
        #self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        x = 0
        items = []
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]/section[2]/article'):
            x = x + 1
            item = SkodaItem()
            item["title"] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]/section[2]/article['+str(x)+']/div/div[1]/div[1]/h2/a/span').re('.+>(.+)</span>')
            #print sel.xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]/section[2]/article['+str(x)+']/div/div[1]/div[1]/h2/a/span').extract()
            item["leeftijd"] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]/section[2]/article['+str(x)+']/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]').re('.+">(.+)</span>')
            item["prijs"] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]/section[2]/article['+str(x)+']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div').re('.+\n +(.+)\n.+')
            item["km"] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]/section[2]/article['+str(x)+']/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[3]').re('.+">(.+)</span>')

            #handle output (print or safe to database)
            items.append(item)
            print item ["title"],item["leeftijd"],item["prijs"],item["km"]
```

Comment: Check your XPath expression in your `Rule`'s `LinkExtractor`: `//a[@class="button secondary medium pagination-next"]/a` looks for children `<A>` elements inside `<A>`'s. Removing the final `/a` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks m8! (jee that's all? have been overlooking it whole day... i'm a beginner..)

Comment: Thought it worked, but i looked wrong. but it doesn't work for me? there are 3 pages and i'm only getting the results back from the first page.

Comment: see my answer for explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to change:

- when using `CrawlSpider`, [you should not redefine the `parse` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?#crawling-rules), it's where all the "magic" happens for this particular spider type

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.

- as I mentioned in the comments, your XPath needs fixing by removing the extra `/a` at the end (links in links will not match any element)
- `CrawlSpider` rules need a callback method if you want to extract items from the followed pages
- to also parse elements from the start URLs, you need to define a [`parse_start_url` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url)

This is a minimalistic `CrawlSpider` following the 3 pages from your sample input, and printing out how many "articles" there are in each page:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class SkodaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "skodas"
    allowed_domains = ["marktplaats.nl"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.marktplaats.nl/z/auto-s/skoda/octavia-trekhaak-stationwagon.html?categoryId=151&priceFrom=1.000%2C00&priceTo=15.000%2C00&yearFrom=2010&mileageTo=150.000&attributes=S%2C1185&attributes=S%2C484&attributes=M%2C11564&startDateFrom=always"
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button secondary medium pagination-next"]',)),
             follow=True,
             callback='parse_page'),
    ]

    def parse_page(self, response):
        articles = response.css('#search-results > section + section > article')
        self.logger.info('%d articles' % len(articles))

    # define this, otherwise "parse_page" will not be called for the URLs in start_urls
    parse_start_url = parse_page
```

Output:

```
$ scrapy runspider 001.py 
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.marktplaats.nl/z/auto-s/skoda/octavia-trekhaak-stationwagon.html?categoryId=151&priceFrom=1.000%2C00&priceTo=15.000%2C00&yearFrom=2010&mileageTo=150.000&attributes=S%2C1185&attributes=S%2C484&attributes=M%2C11564&startDateFrom=always> (referer: None)
2016-02-09 11:07:16 [skodas] INFO: 32 articles
2016-02-09 11:07:17 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.marktplaats.nl/z/auto-s/skoda.html?attributes=S%2C1185+S%2C484+M%2C11564&categoryId=151&currentPage=2&mileageTo=150.000&priceFrom=1.000%2C00&priceTo=15.000%2C00&yearFrom=2010> (referer: http://www.marktplaats.nl/z/auto-s/skoda/octavia-trekhaak-stationwagon.html?categoryId=151&priceFrom=1.000%2C00&priceTo=15.000%2C00&yearFrom=2010&mileageTo=150.000&attributes=S%2C1185&attributes=S%2C484&attributes=M%2C11564&startDateFrom=always)
2016-02-09 11:07:17 [skodas] INFO: 30 articles
2016-02-09 11:07:17 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.marktplaats.nl/z/auto-s/skoda.html?attributes=S%2C1185+S%2C484+M%2C11564&categoryId=151&currentPage=3&mileageTo=150.000&priceFrom=1.000%2C00&priceTo=15.000%2C00&yearFrom=2010> (referer: http://www.marktplaats.nl/z/auto-s/skoda.html?attributes=S%2C1185+S%2C484+M%2C11564&categoryId=151&currentPage=2&mileageTo=150.000&priceFrom=1.000%2C00&priceTo=15.000%2C00&yearFrom=2010)
2016-02-09 11:07:17 [skodas] INFO: 7 articles
2016-02-09 11:07:17 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-02-09 11:07:17 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1919,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 96682,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 9, 10, 7, 17, 638179),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 9, 10, 7, 16, 452272)}
2016-02-09 11:07:17 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```